# Call two objects WSDL

Tags: c#

**The first time I got a very strange WSDL.**

I would like to call the object (interface - InvoiceCheck_Out) do you know how?

[image]

I would like to call the object (variable) do you know how?[image]

Try to call **(it`s OK)**

[image]

Try to call **(How call this?)**

[image]

Comment: Could you please clarify what you mean? I can't tell what is your desire.

Comment: for example WSPI.InvoiceCheck_Out How can I call bacause I get error? string data = WSPI.InvoiceCheck_Out???

Comment: this same is with another picture -> string data = oc.InvoiceCheckRequest ???

Comment: what happens when you call `var data = oc.InvoiceCheckRequest()` if you don't get an error then it's telling me that you are trying to assign a string to a return type that's not a string.. or the Method returns Object of different type.. or the Method is declared as `void` which means it can have a return value.. can you show what the class looks like without posting an Image..

Comment: @MethodMan I added new pictures to post.

Comment: the message tells you exactly what the issue is .. you are trying to assign a property or variable like a method.. would be a lot nicer if you could show the WebService code behind.. it's not like top secret code..also why are you using interfaces to something so simple in regards to creating a web service.. is this something that you are creating or something that your're trying to consume.. I would implement the `KISS` Method.. stands for `Keep it Simple Stupid` also `InvoiceCheckRequest` is a variable not a `Method` based on looking at the pic

Comment: @methodManUnfortunately  WebService was created by another company.

Comment: @MethodMan they tell me I have to call this InvoiceCheckRequest() and later get data from invoiceCheckRequest

Comment: well I am not going to look at this unless you can show some actual code / method signatures pictures are hard to tell what you are doing .. can you not show the Class / code also you're trying to call a method when in fact it's a property and or Interface ...

Comment: you can't call an interface. its a *type* not a *method*.

Comment: OK. I will ask this other company to give me normal void method()

Comment: Its really quite simple. You instantiate a `new InvoiceCheck_OutClient`. Then you call some method on it...But seriously. This is the worst possible way to ask a question possible. DO NOT £$%KING POST IMAGES. A PICTURE IS NOT WORTH A THOUSAND LINE OF CODE. NEXT TIME EITHER POST THE WSDL OR THE BLOODY `REFERENCE.CS`. WITH 811 REP YOU SHOULD KNOW BETTER!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I get from other company correct WSDL now is ok.